# download windows API reference (MSDN) for offline use

Tags: windows, api, documentation, reference

I would like to have a windows API reference document available offline. MSDN is fine, but I also need this kind of information when I don't have access to internet.

pdf, chm, help (for emacs) would be fine.

Surely I am not the first person to want that, but I can't find anything. Could someone please point to a place to find that?

I saw the reference was maybe available in the SDK, but installing it takes ~200 MB, and I only want the documentation.

Comment: 200MB??? The full Windows API documentation will take GigaBytes of offline storage.

Comment: You're right, it's only the code samples. I understand from your comment that my wish won't come true? Not even a basic version? I'm interested in the GUI so far.

Comment: Use [Zeal](https://zealdocs.org/) with MSDN [docset](https://www.rotemy.com/dash/)

Comment: @Darin thats crazy. I have a complete Android reference on my android phone

Answer (score 15):

Just the Win32 API, but it's a thing of beauty: https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32-help-chm/files/

Edit: Dead link replaced with alternate download.

> Although it is now 17 years old, the Win32.hlp file from Microsoft is
> still a useful reference for those, like me, still programming using
> the "flat" Windows API. It still covers 99% of what I need and is much
> more convenient and faster to use than the current MSDN and Windows
> SDK documentation because it is much smaller. It is a file that is
> possible to add to the help menu of your IDE or favorite editor and
> call up instantly, even offline.

Comment: Link is dead now

Comment: Replaced with an alternate version

Answer (score 8):

#### [Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015 Help Downloader](https://github.com/nickdalt/VSHD)

Tool for downloading the Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015 help packages for offline use

[image]

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you explicitly identified the link to this tool ([Visual Studio 2010 Help Downloader](http://vshelpdownloader.codeplex.com/)) -- as it is, I mistook it as just the title to your post.

Comment: Update link,[vshd2012](http://vshd2012.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Seems to be working, fortunately the source is available, needed to use one of the patches to get the downloader to work with a proxy.

Comment: This is no longer needed; just use Microsoft Help Viewer from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

Official [VS2012Documentation.iso & VS2013Documentation.iso](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34794)

Official [MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20955)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seealso/archive/2010/07/26/viewing-the-msdn-documentation-offline.aspx) explaining how you could install it. You can also only [take a subset of it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbosch/archive/2007/04/28/take-parts-of-the-msdn-library-offline-with-packagethis.aspx). You can also [download the library it from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373).

Comment: 2 first links are dead.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio, "Help > Manage Help Settings" you can download the contents to disk. Then you can press F1 to view them.

This feature is even available in Visual Studio Express. You can start the help server manually at `%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0`

Installing the Windows SDK and the .NET 4 help contents took ~700MB for me. There's probably no way around it.

(Windows SDKs used to contain the documentation but it seems like they've stripped it out in v7.1)

You can even do a search offline in the Help, though from my experience the relevant rate is worse than Google.

Edit: *The "Microsoft Help System" is also available in the SDK so you don't need to install Visual Studio to use it*

Comment: trial period?  AFAIK Visual Studio Express versions are licensed forever for free, albeit with fewer features than the other editions.

Comment: Yep, that was a misuse of words. MS just said "we do require that you register your product within 30 days of installation for continued use". Since I installed MSVC 2010 Express just for the compiler tools and I never wanted to register, I kind of mixed it up :P

Comment: If you don't have the Help Viewer: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25795/where-is-the-help-viewer.html "-    Launch Visual Studio
-    Ctrl + Q to go to Quick Search
-    Type 'Help Viewer'
-    Select 'Help Viewer (Individual Component)'
-    Close Visual Studio and click Install button on the Installer"

Answer (score 1):

[Package This!](http://packagethis.codeplex.com/) is a good tool to download and compile MSDN docs as CHM.

Comment: Not working more 05/2014